# How to sort "version" strings with SQL in Snowflake?

Tags: sql, snowflake-cloud-data-platform, sql-order-by, version

I have a column with strings representing release "versions", like:

```
5.14.0
5.10.1
5.1.8
5.1.87
5.1.357
26.3.0
24.1.1
```

How can I sort these in Snowflake? Note that the numeric sort (what we want) is different than the simple string sort.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We discussed this on the dbt Slack - my suggestion moves the sorting transformations into the `order by` - by splitting the string and converting it into an array of integers. Snowflake natively knows how to sort these arrays in the correct order:

```sql
select *
from data
order by (
    select [y[0]::int, y[1]::int, y[2]::int]
    from(
        select split(version_number, '.') y
    )
);
```

Sample data:

```sql
create table data as 
select value version_number
from (table(split_to_table(
$$5.14.0
5.10.1
5.1.8
5.1.87
5.1.357
26.3.0
24.1.1$$, '\n'
    )))
;
```

We can also create a UDF for reusability:

```sql
create function string_to_int_array_3(version_number string)
returns array
as
$$
    select [y[0]::int, y[1]::int, y[2]::int] 
    from(
        select split(version_number, '.') y
    )
$$
;

select *
from data
order by string_to_int_array_3(version_number);
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Using `SPLIT_PART`:

```
SELECT *
FROM data
ORDER BY SPLIT_PART(version_number, '.', 1)::INT,
         SPLIT_PART(version_number, '.', 2)::INT,
         SPLIT_PART(version_number, '.', 3)::INT;
```

Output:

```
VERSION_NUMBER
5.1.8
5.1.87
5.1.357
5.10.1
5.14.0
24.1.1
26.3.0
```

Answer (score 1):

Using `natsort` Python package:

```
create or replace function natural_sort(arr ARRAY)
returns array
language python
runtime_version = '3.8'
packages = ('natsort')
handler = 'sort'
as
$$
import natsort
def sort(arr):
  return natsort.natsorted(arr)
$$;
```

Input data:

```
create table data as 
select value version_number
from (table(split_to_table(
$$5.14.0
5.10.1
5.1.8
5.1.87
5.1.357
26.3.0
24.1.1$$, '\n'
    )))
;
```

Output:

```
SELECT NATURAL_SORT(SELECT ARRAY_AGG(VERSION_NUMBER) FROM data);
-- ["5.1.8", "5.1.87", "5.1.357", "5.10.1", "5.14.0", "24.1.1", "26.3.0" ]
```

or:

```
SELECT VALUE::TEXT AS VERSION_NUMBER
FROM TABLE(FLATTEN(NATURAL_SORT(SELECT ARRAY_AGG(VERSION_NUMBER) FROM data)));
/*
VERSION_NUMBER
5.1.8
5.1.87
5.1.357
5.10.1
5.14.0
24.1.1
26.3.0
*/
```

---

**EDIT - Version 2:**

```
create or replace function natural_sort(str TEXT)
returns array
language python
runtime_version = '3.8'
packages = ('natsort')
handler = 'sort'
as
$$
import natsort
def sort(str):
  return list(natsort.natsort_key(str))
$$;
```

Call:

```
SELECT *
FROM data
ORDER BY natural_sort(version_number);
```

Output:

```
VERSION_NUMBER
5.1.8
5.1.87
5.1.357
5.10.1
5.14.0
24.1.1
26.3.0
```

Comment: Neat answer! I do prefer the SQL one only because performance - but I'm glad to learn `natsort` can do this in Python

Answer (score 0):

Idea: Assuming that digits constitute only positive integers sorting could use `REGEXP_EXTRACT_ALL` to group the input into continuous digits and other characters:

Pseudocode:

```
SELECT *
FROM data
ORDER BY REGEXP_EXTRACT_ALL(version_number,'(\\d+|[^\\d]+)');
```

---

For input:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TABLE data(version_number TEXT) AS 
      SELECT '5.14.0'
UNION SELECT '5.10.1'
UNION SELECT '5.1.8'
UNION SELECT '5.1a'
UNION SELECT '5.2b'
UNION SELECT '5.1.87'
UNION SELECT '2.10'
UNION SELECT '5.1.357'
UNION SELECT '26.3.0'
UNION SELECT '24.1.1';
    
SELECT *, REGEXP_EXTRACT_ALL(version_number,'(\\d+|[^\\d]+)')
FROM data;
```

[image]

---

The tricky part is that each element of array has the data type of `TEXT` and to properly sort it, it requires explicit casting to `INT`.

Unfortunately, there is no `ARRAY_APPLY` function:

```
SELECT *
FROM data
ORDER BY ARRAY_APPLY(REGEXP_EXTRACT_ALL(version_number,'(\\d+|[^\\d]+)')
            ,$$elem -> CASE WHEN elem RLIKE '\\d+' THEN elem::INT ELSE elem END$$);
```

---

Casting each numerical element of `ARRAY` to `INT`:

```
SELECT version_number, 
 ARRAY_AGG(CASE WHEN g.VALUE::TEXT RLIKE '\\d+' THEN g.value::INT ELSE g.value END) 
 WITHIN GROUP(ORDER BY g.INDEX) AS arr_ver
FROM data
,LATERAL FLATTEN(REGEXP_EXTRACT_ALL(version_number,'(\\d+|[^\\d]+)')) g
GROUP BY version_number
ORDER BY arr_ver;
```

Output:

[image]